# Firebase - Fetch Data Without Secure Nodes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Using Firebase, how can I fetch a node, of which some children are secure?

For example...

Data structure:

```
root: {
    clients: {
        c1: { 
            data: {
                name: "person1"
            }
            permissions: {
                clientId: "abc"
                trainerId: "123"
            }
        }
        c2: { 
            data: {
                name: "person2"
            }
            permissions: {
                clientId: "def"
                trainerId: "123"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Security:

```
"clients": {
          "$clientKey": {
                "data": {
                    ".read": "data.parent().child('permissions').child('clientId').val() == auth.token.name || data.parent().child('permissions').child('trainerId').val() == auth.uid",
                    ".write": "data.parent().child('permissions').child('trainerId').val() == auth.uid"
              }
          }
        }
```

So what I am trying to achieve is the following; A client can read their own data. A trainer can read and write any of their clients. If your `id` is in the `permissions` then you can read/write as specified.

However, my issue now becomes, if as a trainer I want to see a list of all clients I have permission to read.

How can I fetch the clients? Trying to just do a data read/fetch on `clients` fails.

Comment: Do these permissions actually work for you in the simulator? I can't get them to work.

Comment: Nope, not for me. I was following an example as seen here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/group-security-in-firebase-database.html I understand its not one answer fits all and the reason I ask is because I can't figure out a working solution, or don't know how it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure your db like so:

```
root: {
  clients: {
    abc: { 
        data: {
            name: "person1"
        },
        trainer: {
            123: true
        }
    },
    def: { 
        data: {
            name: "person2"
        },
        trainer: {
            123: true
        }
    }
  },
  trainers: {
    123: {
      clients: {
        abc: true,
        def: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the following rules.
I think it would be easier to just enforce the read and write rules on the client_id object, like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "clients" : {
      "$client_id" : {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $client_id || data.child('trainer/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write" : "data.child('trainer/'+auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    },
    "trainers": {
      "$trainer_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $trainer_id || data.child('clients/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $trainer_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get a trainer's clients you'd first fetch the trainer's node and then fetch the client's info for each client under the client's node.

Fetching the info of all clients under a trainer (I don't know Obj C but I think this should work.)

```
[[self.trainersRef child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/clients", userId]] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
  for ( FDataSnapshot *child in snapshot.children) {
    [[self.clientsRef child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/data", child.key]] observerEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull dataSnapshot) {
      // Client info available here.
    }];
  }
}];
```

Comment: Added Obj C query.